# How to use the method of Monte Carlo to search for the limit probabilities

Tags: c#, algorithm, statistics, montecarlo

I want to understand how to use the method of Monte Carlo to search for the limit probabilities of the some system S.

For example:

```
    S0  S1  S2  S3
S0  0.1 0.9 0   0
S1  0   0.2 0.3 0.5
S2  0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2
S3  0.5 0   0.4 0.1
```

As I understand the method we need to generate a some number (x) and then compare the probability:

```
if x 
   0   <= x < 0.1 => S0 -> S0
   0.1 <= x < 0.9 => S0 -> S1
   0.9 <= x < 0.9 => S0 -> S2
   0.9 <= x < 0.9 => S0 -> S3
   0.9 <= x < 1   => S0 -> S4
```

when S4 - limit (border)

Similarly for other states.

Following this approach I can count the number of transitions:

```
  static double[] SimpleMonte(double[][] a, int iter = 1)
    {
        var n = a.GetLength(0);

        var p =
            a
            .Select(x => x.Select((_, i) => x.Take(i + 1).Sum()).ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        Random rand = new Random();

        double[] X = new double[n];
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            double count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
            {
                int row = x;
                bool notG = true;
                Console.Write("{0} -> ", row);
                while (notG)
                {

                    var e = rand.NextDouble();
                    Console.Write("({0})", Math.Round(e, 2));
                    bool ch = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (p[row][j] <= e && e < p[row][j + 1])
                        {
                            row = j + 1;
                            ch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!ch)
                        notG = false;
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0} -> ", row);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            X[x] = count / iter;
        }
        return X;
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nJF5sm

I will be glad to hear a hint on what to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Do you want to solve `S x = x`, i.e. find the stationary setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a practical sense, the best way to find a limit of the a system like that is repeated squaring of the matrix until the entries converge. This works because it is a stochastic matrix (sum of each row equals 1). When I tried it I got an answer of:

```
S0        S1        S2        S3
0.1939252 0.2593458 0.3294393 0.2172897
```

which gives the average probabilities that you will be in a particular state.

To use a Monte Carlo method, you should generate the random numbers like you have done and keep count of the transitions. Then the average probability that you're in a certain state is

`(Amount of Transitions to State S)/(Total Transitions)`

as your Total Transitions gets large enough.

In the code you provided, if you keep increasing the size of your `iter` variable (and it does need to be relatively large) the last four lines of your output should converge to the numbers above. I hope that helps.

---

In the original code there was a mistake that prevented a transition to the initial state. That is the correct version:

```
static double[] SimpleMonte(double[][] a, int iter = 10000)
    {
        var n = a.GetLength(0);

        var p =
            a
            .Select(x => x.Select((_, i) => x.Take(i + 1).Sum()).ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        Random rand = new Random();
        double[] X = new double[n];
        int row = rand.Next(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
        {
            var e = rand.NextDouble();
            X[row]++;
            if (e < p[row][0])
                row = 0;
            else
                for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (p[row][j] <= e && e < p[row][j + 1])
                    {
                        row = j + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }
        return X.Select(x => x / iter).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: you know, I took a break and came to this conclusion myself. Thank you :)